# Phrase question

Tags: sentence-usage, comparative-constructions

I will hit on your face 
I will hit in your face which one is correct

I will slap on your face
I will slap in your face which one is correct

I will say on your face
I will say to your face which one is correct

Please explain properly

Comment: This is easily found in a dictionary; slap takes a direct object (you, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

1. **I will hit you in the face**, or **I will hit your face**. Either is correct.
2. **I will slap your face**, or **I will slap you in the face**. Either is correct.
3. **I will say to your face**. If everyone knows what is being said, it is common to say, **I will say it to your face.**